# Procurar apartir de uma propriedade em uma list de uma determinada classe

Tags: c#, linq

Estou tentando filtrar os resultados a partir de uma propriedade de uma classe, dentro de uma lista. Hoje eu possuo a seguinte estrutura :

```
public class Jogo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
        public List<Jogador> Jogadores  { get; set; }
    }
```

A minha classe jogador possui as seguintes propriedades:

```
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public int NumeroCamisa { get; set; }
```

Inicialmente, a minha lista continha apenas uma string. Com isso, eu consigo utilizar o Contains.

```
return await _context.jogos.AsQueryable()
                    .Where(x => x.Titulo.Contains("nome do jogo") 
                        && x.informacoes.Contains("numero da camisa) 
                        || x.informacoes.Contains("nome do jogador")
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Ocorre que depois que eu tipei a lista para a classe jogador me deparei com o seguinte erro:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Model.Jogador'.
```

Pretendo procurar pelo titulo do jogo, nome do jogador e o número da camisa.

Procurei outros tópicos e estou enfrentando bastante dificuldade em fazer de um modo que consigo procurar um jogo pelo título ou nome ou numero da camisa.

Tentei utilizando o Linq com o Where, Contains, Find.

Comment: Buenas amigo, acredito que deve ajustar a consulta para buscar dentro do objeto Jogador, mais ou menos asism: return await _context.jogos.AsQueryable() .Where(x => x.Titulo.Contains("nome do jogo") && x.Jogadores.FirstOrDefault(j => j.Nome.Contains("nome do jogador" || j.NumeroCamisa == 12) != null).ToListAsync();

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!

Fiz da seguinte forma, utilizei o **Any** para acessar a lista, e o **Contains** para fazer a busca dentro dela :

```
return await _context.jogos.AsQueryable()
                .Where(x => x.Titulo.Contains("nome do jogo") 
                    || x. Jogadores.Any(x => x.Nome.Contains("nome jogador") 
                .ToListAsync();
```